# Adjust Font Size and Decimal Places in R Boxplot (ggpubr)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am using the R package GGPubr to make Boxplots.  I really like the nice visuals that it provides but am having problems. Does anyone know how to increase the font size of the numbers on the axes, and the axis labels, and class labels?  Also how do I set the mean values so that they only display 2 decimal places?

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
library("ggpubr")
mydata <- read.csv("C:\\temp\\ndvi.csv")
ggboxplot(mydata, x = "class", y = "NDVI", 
      color = "class",
      order = c("Conifer", "Deciduous", "Grasslands"),  ggtheme=theme_gray(),
      ylab = "NDVI Value", xlab = "Land Cover Class",
      add="mean",
      font.label = list(size = 30, face = "bold"))+ stat_summary(fun.data 
= function(x) data.frame(y=1, label = paste("Mean=",mean(x))),  geom="text")
+theme(legend.position="none")
```

And the csv:

```
NDVI,class
0.25,Conifer
0.27,Conifer
0.29,Conifer
0.403,Deciduous
0.38,Deciduous
0.365,Deciduous
0.31983489,Grasslands
0.32005,Grasslands
0.328887766,Grasslands
```

I would prefer to achieve the desired effects above with GGPubr rather than boxplot() or ggplot/ggplot 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where we use `round()` to take care of the two decimal places and add another `theme()` to change the text size.

```
ggboxplot(mydata, x = "class", y = "NDVI", 
          color = "class",
          order = c("Conifer", "Deciduous", "Grasslands"),  ggtheme=theme_gray(),
          ylab = "NDVI Value", xlab = "Land Cover Class",
          add="mean",
          font.label = list(size = 30, face = "bold")) +
  # use round() and set y = .45 
  stat_summary(fun.data = function(x) data.frame(y=1, label = paste("Mean=", round(mean(x), 2))), geom="text") + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16)) # change text size of theme components
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @markus. The code for rounding decimals and text works great!